# Error with \mbox

Tags: amsmath, boxes

I have been using `amsmath` package for an article. I need to show the units for various physical processes but I do not want the units to be italic. To get non italic font inside the `$$` environment, I am using `$(\mbox{m^{-2}})$`. But I am getting this error  `- - "Missing $ inserted. $(\mbox{m^{-2}}".`

If I remove `"^"` in the above expression, I am not getting any error. What should I do to get something raised to some power using `\mbox`?

Comment: Not tested. But I think you can try placing math environment ($$) inside mbox

Comment: did it already ,, $$ suppresses  mbox if mbox  is put inside $$. i just used \mathrm and got no problem.

Comment: Welcome, check out package `siunitx`. It helps you with typesetting units. `\si{\per\meter\squared}`

Comment: ` $(\mbox{$m^2$})$`should work, but `\si{\m\squared}` is so much simpler, and you have a number, `\SI{12}{\m\squared}` gives the correct nobreak thin space between number and unit.

Comment: `$(\mathrm{m}^{-2})$`

Comment: `$\mbox{m^{-2}}$` cannot possibly work; try `$\mbox{m}^{-2}$` instead. The argument of `\mbox` should just be the letter `m`. Better still, load the `siunitx` package and write either `\si{\meter\tothe{-2}}` or `\si{\per\meter\squared}`. The `\si` macro can be used in and out of math mode.

Comment: The mathtools package provides \mathmbox and several other boxes.

Comment: Thanks for the help all

 $(\mathrm{m}^{-2})$ and \mbox{m}^{-2} are working fine .